# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

How to fix this error or what I can change or implement?

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and continuous-multioutput targets

full code attached below
A little info on the csv file it has 15 classes 78 input dimensions and over 600,000 samples

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/bam/train.csv", header=0, dtype=object)
dataset = dataframe.values
X_train = dataset[:,0:78].astype(float)
y_train = dataset[:,78]
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("C:/Users/bam/test.csv", header=0, dtype=object)
dataset = dataframe.values
X_test = dataset[:,0:78].astype(float)
y_test = dataset[:,78]
##my version for encoding
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_Yone = encoder.transform(y_train)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Yone)
#encode our testing set
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_test)
encoded_Ytwo = encoder.transform(y_test)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Ytwo)

#Creating an object of StandardScaler trial run to try and improve accuracy from 90% baseline*
sc = StandardScaler()
#Scaling the data using the StandardScaler() object
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

neural_classifier = Sequential()
#output_dim = number of nuerons in first hidden layer
#init = initializing the weights of the neural network
#input_dim = number of neuron in the input layer = number of input features = 78 
#Actiavtion = activation function that is used in each layer
#Dense is the type of layer
#The neural network needs to start with some weights and then iteratively update them to better values. The term kernel_initializer is a fancy term for which statistical distribution or function to use for initialising the weights. In case of statistical distribution, the library will generate numbers from that statistical distribution and use as starting weights.
#Input layer
neural_classifier.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 78))

neural_classifier.add(Dense(150, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
neural_classifier.add(Dense(200, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
neural_classifier.add(Dense(250, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
neural_classifier.add(Dense(300, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
neural_classifier.add(Dense(350, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
neural_classifier.add(Dense(400, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
neural_classifier.add(Dense(250, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
neural_classifier.add(Dense(300, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
# output layer has 15 neurons because there are 15 classes in dataset
#Since it is a multiclass classification problem hence we are using the softmax activation function
neural_classifier.add(Dense(15, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'softmax'))
neural_classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
neural_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 32, epochs = 2)
#Predicting the labels for the test data
y_pred = neural_classifier.predict(X_test)
#Calculating the accuracy score
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
#Calculating the precision score
precision = metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
#Calculating the recall score
recall = metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
#Calculating the f1-score
f1score = metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')
print("Accuracy score of the model is :", accuracy)
print("precision score of the model is :", precision)
print("Recall score of the model is :", recall)
print("f1-score of the model is :", f1score)
```

[full error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IifF1.png)

Answer (score 0):

in your example you are creating a matrix for the classes using

```
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Yone)
```

you need to convert back y_test from one hot encoded to simple array otherwise you can't use  metrics.accuracy_score

one way using numpy is

```
y_lab = np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
```

so at the head of the file just import numpy like this

```
import numpy as np
```

and then before call metrics.accuracy create the y_lab variable

```
y_lab = np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
```

and use y_lab in metrics.accuracy

here's a link to explain how and why use one-hot encoded https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/